# Why is my program outputting special characters from csv file c++

Tags: c++, csv

So i'm using vs code and im trying to output a csv file using c++. There's no errors but I am currently getting some weird characters as the output instead of the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  ifstream ip("/Users/safdarjamil/Desktop/cab_rides/src/cab_rides.csv");

  if(!ip.is_open()) std::cout << "ERROR: File Open" << '\n';

  string firstname;
  string lastname;
  string age;
  string weight;

  while(ip.good()){

    getline(ip,firstname,',');
    getline(ip,lastname,',');
    getline(ip,age,',');
    getline(ip,weight,'\n');

    std::cout << "Name: "<<firstname<< " "<<lastname << '\n';
    std::cout << "Age: "<<age << '\n';
    std::cout << "Weight: "<<weight << '\n';
    std::cout << "-------------------" << '\n';
  }

  ip.close();
}
```

Here is my csv file:

```
cool,   nice,   26, 78
John,   More,   33, 80
yes,    no,     22, 70
hello,  bye,    27, 65
```

Here is the output:

```
Name: ��T

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.53 seconds
```

Comment: Are you sure `cab_rides.csv` is actually a csv file and not an excel file renamed as a csv file?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Ka3TTaY9b).  Most likely, the file has a non-UTF8 encoding and possibly a BOM (byte order mark) indicating that encoding.  You can see this if you open it in a hex editor.  Copy your file's text out of your question here, delete the original file, and paste this text into a new file.  If your text editor is inserting BOM always, then it's a crappy text editor.  Either use a different one, or find the right setting to make UTF8 default, or upgrade your program to handle BOM and different character encodings.

Comment: `while(ip.good())` ensures that the state of the stream is good at the time of the test. It does not and can not guarantee that data read by the four `getline`s that follow the test is valid. You need to read data, test that you read data successfully, and then use the data. You are currently testing, then reading, and then using the data regardless of possible failure. This is a bug.

Comment: FYI, if there is an error opening the file, your program continues.  You may want to `return` from main or eliminate the test for file open.